# Передаче полей в другой класс

Tags: c#, unity3d, ооп

Дело в С# Unity. Нужно передать данные поля в другой класс, но дело в том что при передаче через объекты, через методы возвращающие значения, через ссылочные типы, и через свойства, поле в которую была записана другое поле из исходного класса - пустует. Создаются поля в исходном классе пустыми, а в методе Start(), его значения перезаписывается, возможно дело в том что, он почему-то берет поле пока она была пустым, но не пойму почему. В исходном классе при проверке значений в полях, всё работает правильно.

**Исходный класс:**

```
    public int FoodRate;
    internal GameObject[] Foods = new GameObject[] { };

    void Start()
    {
        Array.Resize(ref Foods, Foods.Length + FoodRate);
        for (int i = 0; i < FoodRate; i++)
        {
            Foods[i] = Instantiate(Food, new Vector3(UnityEngine.Random.Range(transform.position.x - SegmentLengthX(), transform.position.x + SegmentLengthX()), transform.position.y + 0.2f, UnityEngine.Random.Range(transform.position.z + SegmentLengthZ(), transform.position.z - SegmentLengthZ())), Quaternion.identity);
        }
    }
```

**Другой класс:**

```
    private static RandomFoodSpawn RFS = new RandomFoodSpawn();
    private int _FoodRate = RFS.FoodRate;
    private GameObject[] _Foods = RFS.Foods;

    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log(_FoodRate);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант то, что нужно обработать в первую очередь отправить в `Awake()`, а остальное оставить в `Start()`